# get indices for grep in R

Tags: r, tm

I am working on text mining using `tm` package. I have corpus, with 320 documents in it, I would like to search for a keyword in corpus contents, such that it should return document number, So I have written like

```
miningCases <- lapply(myCorpusCopy,function(x){grepl(as.character(x), pattern = "\\<mining")})
```

Here are the first 8 results, when I print `miningCases`

```
[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE

[[4]]
[1] FALSE

[[5]]
[1] FALSE

[[6]]
[1] FALSE

[[7]]
[1] TRUE

[[8]]
[1] FALSE
```

I want to get something like 1 7, such it found pattern in 1st and 7th document. Any way to do this?

Comment: You mean you want to know `which` ones are true? Hint hint.

Comment: yeah @RichScriven

Comment: ifelse(lapply(myCorpusCopy,function(x){grep(as.character(x), pattern = "\\<mining")}),1,0)
It is working When i do like this

Comment: `which(unlist(miningCases))`. Or use `sapply()` instead of `lapply()` and you then it's just `which(miningCases)`.

Comment: Thank you, This is much better than my solution. @RichScriven